# Blank screen on device; simulator working fine

Tags: iphone, ios

I am writing an iOS app with a navigation controller. When I open it up on the Simulator, it runs fine. When I run it on the device, a blank screen is displayed below the status bar. Plus I can't figure out where my RootViewController is made to be the default view (which I suspect is the root of my problem).

```
@class RootViewController;

@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    RootViewController *viewController;

    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet RootViewController *viewController;
```

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Set the navigation controller as the window's root view controller and display.
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // ...

    return YES;
}
```

RootViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Main Menu";
}
```

No viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, etc.

Displays a table of 0 elements.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    tv.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
        cell = newsCell;
    else if (indexPath.row == 1)
        cell = configureCell;
    else if (indexPath.row == 2)
        cell = aboutCell;

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tv numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0;
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate Methods


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tv
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 84;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tv
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (0 == indexPath.row)
    {
    }
    else if (1 == indexPath.row)
    {
    }
    else if (2 == indexPath.row)
    {
    }
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [tableView release];
    [newsCell release];
    [configureCell release];
    [aboutCell release];
}
```

RootViewController.h

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    UITableView *tableView;
    IBOutlet UIView *displaySplashScreen;
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *newsCell, *configureCell, *aboutCell;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues here. First, your AppDelegate header should read:

```
@class RootViewController;

@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    RootViewController *rootViewController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Then, in the implementation, add the root to the navigation controller and the navController to the window like this:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation MyAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
                                             initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

    [window addSubview:[navController view]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This cleans up my code, for which I am very grateful. However, it does not clear up the black screen displayed on my device, with only a status bar on top.

Comment: Then I suggest you post the code for the rootViewController. Specifically, viewDidLoad and, if applicable, viewWillAppear. The problem may be there.

Comment: Amendments are made to original post. Doubtful they will be of any help.

Comment: Try `self.navigationItem.title = @"Main Menu"`. Just for kicks, also try changing the background color (`self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`) and see what happens. My guess is that things aren't hooked up in the IB correctly.

Comment: self.navigationItem.title = @"Main Menu" creates no changes, and self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; creates no changes. That is, everything looks normal (not red) in the simulator, but the device has a black screen with a white status bar.

All of my links are consistent within the Interface builder. aboutCell, configureCell, and newsCell are linked to Table View Cells. view is linked to View. tableView is linked to Table View. Table View's dataSource and delegate are linked to File's Owner. This is correct, no?

Comment: @Scott, You have 0 rows in your sections! Of course the `tableView` is blank. Also, the `tableView` is not declared as an `IBOutlet`. Either declare it as such and make the connections in the IB or create it (with `alloc` and `init`) in the implementation.

Comment: @PengOne, I was trying to show a blank table for debugging purposes as nothing was showing up. Turns out that rebuilding the IB did the trick, for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 1):

PengOne's answer is correct, except I'd make one small change. Do this:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation MyAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    rootViewcontroller = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
                                         initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = navController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

It's a better way to show a nav controller. As PengOne also said, it has to be a problem with your Interface Builder file. Unhook everything then hook it up again to see if the problem persists. If it does, check to make sure everything is named correctly. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, I reconstructed the IB files (RootViewController and MainWindow), with no success. I don't see how IB would cause problems exclusive to the device and not to the simulator. Anyways, I just reconstructed the entire project from scratch, and everything now works on both simulator and device. Nothing learned, but it works.

Comment: Odd, must have been something very rare. Sometimes, "cleaning" the project (Product > Clean) will help funky issues like that. Sorry it caused you such a headache, but I'm glad it works now.